# Calculate the MAX of variables that start with the same string in (R?

Tags: r

I have data that looks something like this:

```
data = data.frame(Homework.1 = as.integer(c(10,6,8,NA,NA,NA)), 
                  Homework.1.German = as.integer(c(5,NA,NA,NA,8,NA)), 
                  Homework.1.spanish = as.integer(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,7,10)),
                  Homework.2 = as.integer(c(7,3,10,NA,NA,NA)), 
                  Homework.2.German = as.integer(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,9,NA)))
```

But with more people, homeworks, and languages.

I want to create a new variable in the data frame that is the sum of the max of all the homeworks

Something like

```
data$max <- apply(data[grep("Homework.1", names(data))], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE) +
  apply(data[grep("Homework.2", names(data))], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pmax`:

```
data$final <- with(data,
    pmax(Homework.1, Homework.1.German, Homework.1.Spanish, na.rm=TRUE) +
    pmax(Homework.2, Homework.2.German, Homework.2.Spanish, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Or, since you know something about the structure of the variable names:

```
q1 <- grep("\\.1", names(data))
q2 <- grep("\\.2", names(data))
data$final <- do.call(pmax, c(data[q1], na.rm=TRUE)) +
              do.call(pmax, c(data[q2], na.rm=TRUE))
```